# Passing object RouteValues to the search button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, frontend, routevalues

I would like to pass `object RouteValues` parameter to that button

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search-box">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@Model.searchString" class="search-text form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                Search
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I know how to do it with Html.ActionLink, but I don't know where to put it in that button class.
Routevalues that I would like to pass look like this:

```
new { sortOrder = Model.CurrentSort}
```

Is there any easy way to pass those here to my button?

Comment: What do you mean _to the button_? Your subitting a `form` so it needs to be in the forms `action` attribute. Use the `@Html.BeginForm()` method.

Comment: if you know how to use it in Html.ActionLink , can't you create a Html.ActionLink with bootstrap css and display it as a button?

Answer (score 0):

If you need submit form use `@Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@Html.BeginForm("NAME_METHOD_FROM_YOUR_CONTROLLER", "FORM_METHOD.POST OR GET")
{
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search-box">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@Model.searchString" class="search-text form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
            Search
        </button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
}
```

All input in your form will send to your controller.
Another way if you need use form method get, you can change button to `<a>` with href attributes: `<a href="/Controller_Name/Method/Parameter(optional)" />` the same how your route map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",
                           new { sortOrder = Model.CurrentSort }, FormMethod.Post, null){

    }

or you can use a hidden field in your form:
<input type="hidden" name="sortOrder" value="@Model.CurrentSort" />
```